# How to pass a parameter to Modal in for loop

Tags: c#, razor

I have a bootstrap modal in a for loop and want to pass a few Parameters to each individual modal to 1. display the parameter and 2. submit an individual form to controller with the parameters to it. Even though I have the modal in the for loop, the parameters dont change and it seems like its just one modal instead of one for each in the for loop.

```
@renderedDay.DayOfWeek, @DayDate
   <table id="item" style="background: white; width: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
        @{
           for (int h = 0; h < Model.Times.Count; h++)
           {
              <tr>
                 <td>
                  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                  <button style="height:100%; width:100%;" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                                                    Reservieren
                   </button>

                   <!-- Modal -->
                   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                   <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                                                                @renderedDay.DayOfWeek, @DayDate
                   <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Termin Reservierung (19.01.2019 / 08:30)</h5>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   </button>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              <form class="form-inline">
                <hr />Falls Sie für einen anderen USZ-Mitarbeiter einen Termin reservieren wollen, geben Sie dessen USZ-Kürzen unten ein. <hr />
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="USZ-Kürzel" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">

           <div class="input-group-append">
                                                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button">Mitarbeiter suchen</button>
                                                                        </div>
           </div>

                                                                </form>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Reservieren</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
```

Comment: I do not see you passing any parameters that depend on the loop variable `h`. Did you want to pass `@Model.Times[h].DayOfWeek` instead of `@renderedDay.DayOfWeek`?

Comment: As a side note, it should probably be "... geben Sie dessen USZ-Kürze**l** unten ein." instead of "USZ-Kürze**n**".

Comment: Thanks. I baisicly have a weekly calendar that has a cell for multiple times for each day. So 21.01.2019 has multiple times. 07:00, 07:30, 8:00 ect ect. Thats what the @Model.Times[h].TimeString is for. I baisicly want to have a dynamic Modal for each of those times for every day. You get what im trying?